# Js replace in img Tag

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have this function to replace image attributes:

```
jQuery(function() {   
   jQuery(".lightbox-enabled img").each(function() {   
        imgh = jQuery(this).height();  
        lbh = jQuery('.lightbox-enabled').height();  
        lbw = jQuery('.lightbox-enabled').width();  
        jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace(/width="218"/g, 'width="300"'));  

    });          
});
```

There is an error, but where?

I also had it in another way, but there each image had the same source....

Comment: You can see exactly where and what the error is if you open the javascript console of your browser.

Comment: The console does not show any error.

Comment: then where exactly are you seeing an error? How does it manifest?

Comment: I see that the width is not replaced with the new value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery for that, which is more robust than using a regex. Use `.attr(..)` for setting/getting. 
You can get the check that it is 218 before with  `jQuery("[width=218]")`
So:

```
jQuery(function() {   
   jQuery(".lightbox-enabled img").each(function() {   
        imgh = jQuery(this).height();  
        lbh = jQuery('.lightbox-enabled').height();  
        lbw = jQuery('.lightbox-enabled').width();

        jQuery(this).find("[width=218]").attr("width", 300); //some elements. 

    });          
});
```